# Choropleth Map Challenge Explanation// Need to replicate in my data

Tags: r, choropleth

I am replicated the Choropleth Map with the code provided by Hadley. My data is a csv containing a country State name,no. of Murder attempted, no. of Assaultand no. of Rape.
I need to plot a geographic heat map of the country where the darkest color will represent the larger number of crime in that state and so on.

Code: (which i try to replicate)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
unemp2 <- read.csv("USA_State.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

county_df1 <- map_data("state")

names(county_df1) <- c("long", "lat", "group", "order", "state", "state1")
county_df1$state1 <- NULL

state_df <- map_data("state")

# Combine together 
choropleth <- merge(county_df1, unemp2, by = c("state"))
choropleth <- choropleth[order(choropleth$order), ]
# Discretise rate to use with Brewer colour scheme - many options here
# choropleth$rate_d <- cut_number(choropleth$rate, 5)
# choropleth$rate_d <- cut_interval(choropleth$rate, 5)
# Nathan's choice is a little odd:
choropleth$rate_d <- cut(choropleth$Assault, breaks = c(seq(0, 10, by = 2), 35))

# Once you have the data in the right format, recreating the plot is straight
# forward.
library(scales)
ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = rate_d), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour = "white", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuRd")

# Takes a while to draw because ggplot2 not very efficient with large numbers
# of polygons :(
```

#

The part where "choropleth$rate_d" is being created, i am not sure how to use that in my data. I don't have much idea about it. 
Can anybody please explain me the original code or could help with my code.
Let me know if i am not clear

Comment: I believe that part of the code is breaking the rates of one or more of the crimes into "buckets", which creates a factor.  That factor is what determines the color of each state.  So, for example, all states with a rate at the lowest bucket will have the same color.

Answer (score 2):

There is literally a *plethora* of code on how to generate choropleths in ggplot2 all over SO and the internet. The following code generates some data since you didn't provide any and gives you a base template with a proper projection:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Cleans the canvas well for a map ----------------------------------------

theme_map <- function(base_size=9, base_family="") {
  require(grid)
  theme_bw(base_size=base_size, base_family=base_family) %+replace%
    theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          panel.background=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"),
          plot.background=element_blank(),
          legend.justification = c(0,0), 
          legend.position = c(0,0)
    )
}

# Generate some data ------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(100)
choro_data <- data.frame(region=tolower(state.name),
                         Murder=sample(1:20, length(state.name), replace=TRUE),
                         Assault=sample(c(1:10, 35), length(state.name), replace=TRUE),
                         Rape=sample(1:40, length(state.name), replace=TRUE), 
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

choro_data$rate_d <- cut(choro_data$Assault, breaks = c(seq(0, 10, by = 2), 35))

# The core choropleth code ------------------------------------------------

us <- map_data("state")
us <- fortify(us, region="region")

# plot --------------------------------------------------------------------

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region, group=group),
                    fill="white", color="white", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=choro_data, map=us, 
                    aes(fill=rate_d, map_id=region), 
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_map("albers", lat0=39, lat1=45)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_brewer(name="Rate")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

The two `geom_map` calls make it possible to have a data frame of values that may have missing region ids (and saves from having to join a bunch of data to the map itself). The first `geom_map` draws a base map polygons, the second overlays fills. This particular one needs some more aesthetic work (borders, fonts, cleanup legend labels, etc) but I had to leave *some* work for you to do.

I'd strongly suggest an ordered, horizontal bar chart for the data you're trying to present. I doubt the geography will lend any insight into it.

Comment: It'd be really great if this `theme_map` got included in the `ggthemes` package. If you don't have time, I'd make a pull request for you.

Comment: I had not thought about that @Gregor. Totally cool idea. I'll fork and do that today.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: could you add a note to explain %+replace%?

Comment: @lawyeR maybe just look at `?"%+replace%"`

Comment: @lawyeR No need to apologize! Just making sure you knew how to look up help for binary operators.